# Javascript private class fields or methods not working in iOS Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, safari

Do Javascript private fields or methods using `#` work in iOS?

For example, I have this class:

```
Class A { 
    #privateFunction() {return ""} 
}
```

Creating an instance of class A works in Android and desktop. But in iOS, I get the following error: `cannot find variable: A`

I know the error is related to iOS, because if I made the `privateFunction` public, it works.

I'm testing the code on a real iPhone device updated to the latest iOS version.

**Update:** I updated iOS to 14.5.1 but nothing changed.

Comment: That is still experimental I believe

Comment: Oh, i will have to rebuild the whole class then. Thanks

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20field this site tells which browsers has it covered

Comment: @StepPen-codes - No, not experimental anymore, but still only **just now** supported by JavaScriptCore in the wild.

Comment: Yeah it was in my answer just now

Comment: You're conflating "private class fields" and "private class methods". Safari now supports private fields but not private methods. https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20class

Answer (score 4):

On iOS, even Chrome uses Apple's JavaScriptCore JavaScript engine instead of its usual V8 (and uses the WebKit rendering engine, instead of the usual Blink) because of Apple policies¹ (this is true of all other browsers as well).

JavaScriptCore only **just** added support for private fields in iOS 14.5, so you'll need to be on a completely up-to-date device (as of this writing). The proposal is no longer "in progress," it's in the specification (as of the last TC39 meeting).

---

¹ They can't use their own JavaScript engines because that would require allocating executable memory, which Apple only allows Apple apps to do. (V8 did add an interpreter-only mode, but JavaScriptCore is quite a good JavaScript engine and the iOS Chrome folks just use it instead.) They can't use their own rendering engines because Apple doesn't want them to, you **have** to use their WebView component instead.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the clarification, i check the iOS version and it was 14.4.2 i will update it and test the code again

Answer (score 3):

**JS Private Field is supported in Safari & Chrome IOS 14.5 (released 10 days ago).**

Safari & Chrome in IOS **must be updated to 14.5** for the Class Private fields to work

Click the link below for more information in browser compatibilities,

https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20field

Comment: I checked the iOS version and it was 14.4.2 i will update it and test the code again thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote there, i.e. `#privateFunction()`, is a private method, not a private field.

### Private methods are unsupported in Safari older than version 15

At the time of writing, this is the browser support in [MDN according to the *Private class features* page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields):

[image]

Because **private class methods** are not supported by any existing Safari version, it didn't work for you on iOS 14.5.1 either.

Since iOS devices remain very popular, my advice at this time would be to avoid using most (if not all) of these features listed above until such time in the future when browser compatibility improves.

The **good news** is that Safari 15 on iOS 15 and macOS 12 supports private class methods and accessors, according to [the official release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15-release-notes#JavaScript).

Comment: **Backstory:** I hit this snag with a client for whom I wrote a JavaScript module with a private method. After some time, the client complained that none of their customers on iOS devices can see the website properly. I converted the method to a public method to make it work. The method name is long and unique, hence any conflicts would be unlikely.

Comment: Looks like private method support was added in Safari 15 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15-release-notes#:~:text=Added%20support%20for%20private%20class%20methods%20and%20accessors